# Issue in calendar script

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on a site your can see the demo here https://masborn.com/theretreatpalmdubai/

The data picker is calendar is not working here.

```
jQuery(function () {
    jQuery("#bookdate").daterange({
        showButtonPanel: true,
        closeText: "X",
        onClose: function () {
            jQuery(".bookinginputs").css("display", "block");
        },
        onSelect: function (){
            jQuery("#demodate").css("display", "none");
            jQuery(".ui-datepicker-close").css("display", "none");
        }

    });
});
```

I have spend many time on it and not find what is the issue here. Can any one give some input?

Comment: Try with jQuery("#bookdate").datepicker({

Answer (score 0):

From the jquery ui documentation, its called "datepicker" not "daterange".

Also, consider using the $ shortcut instead of jQuery, it makes it easier to read.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>jQuery UI Datepicker - Default functionality</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
  } );
  </script>
</head>
<body>

<p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"></p>


</body>
</html>
```